# Running a function in the background of every page of a Web Application

Tags: asp.net, performance, web-services, asp-classic, background-process

Ok so I have a web application with many pages. The pages are pretty much written in Classic ASP and ASP.Net, eventually everything will go to ASP.net. I want to implement a new function that is constantly running a check of a database table and will create a new pop up window if there is a match to certain criteria, I want this running regardless of the page you are on. Currently the site is set up with frames that are the same for every page, so with the way the site is set up now I can just embed my new function in the frame and it will be available for everything.

However, I will be moving away from frames in the future. I was wondering if there was a way to have my function run on every page without adding it to the code of every page. I'm looking for a way to run this background service without having a new/different window open in the background.

Any resources or ideas will be greatly appreciated, I've been stumped on this concept for a few days now.

Comment: Why not just add the code into a [Master Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)?

Comment: Thats what I was originally thinking, but if I do that, does that mean I would just have to call my function when each page loads?

Comment: There's a `Page_Load` event for the Master Page.

Comment: ok, so I put my function in the Page_Load event in the master page and then it will run when any page loads and I wont have to have individuals calls in each child page

Comment: Well, there are two Page_Load events - one for the master page and one for the current page, but yes - drop it in the Page_Load of the master page.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a "base page" that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page.
Add your code in the Page_Load event there.

Then let your pages inherit from "base page", and thats it.